# nested if else function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a barcode verify function to an item picking webapp page and i have the javascript as this:

```
 function barcodeSubmit () {

 if (barcode1 != barcode || barcode2 != barcode) {
   if (PUT_LPN == "") {
  barcodeF.focus();
  return false;
  }  
 } else {
 if (barcode1 != barcode || barcode2 != barcode) {
 if (PUT_LPN != "") {
     barcodeF.focus();
     return false;
     }  
   }
 }
} else {
 if (barcode1 == barcode || barcode2 == barcode) {
 if (PUT_LPN == "") {
    PUT_LPN.focus();
    return false;
  }  
 }
}
 else {
  if (barcode1 == barcode || barcode2 == barcode) {
  if (PUT_LPN != "") {
    return true;
   }  
  }
 }
}
```

When I submit this form it does not submit and I can not get it to do the function its connected to an onclick input field . It does call when I make it simpler it will execute what I want. I also tried it without the else statements and came out with slightly different result but still not triggering event properly

Comment: "When I submit this form i  ", here `this` refer to which form

Comment: You have one `if` with 4 `else` which is wrong. Use `else if`

Comment: If (){}else if(){} else if(){} else{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use switch instead:

```
switch(true) {
    case ((barcode1 != barcode || barcode2 != barcode) && PUT_LPN == ""):
        barcodeF.focus();
        return false;
    case ((barcode1 != barcode || barcode2 != barcode) && PUT_LPN != ""):
        barcodeF.focus();
        return false;
    case ((barcode1 == barcode || barcode2 == barcode) && PUT_LPN == ""):
        PUT_LPN.focus();
        return false;
    case ((barcode1 == barcode || barcode2 == barcode) && PUT_LPN != ""):
        return true;
    default:
        return true;
}
```

You can remove default case if not needed

Answer (score 1):

Your code having lot of problems you are using one `if` and 4 `else` and some unused conditions also try following:

```
function barcodeSubmit() {

    if (barcode1 != barcode || barcode2 != barcode) {
        if (PUT_LPN == "") {
            barcodeF.focus();
            return false;
        } else if (PUT_LPN != "") {
            barcodeF.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (barcode1 == barcode || barcode2 == barcode) {
        if (PUT_LPN == "") {
            PUT_LPN.focus();
            return false;
        } else if (PUT_LPN != "") {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like following

```html
function barcodeSubmit () {

 if (barcode1 != barcode || barcode2 != barcode) {
 if (PUT_LPN == "") {
   barcodeF.focus();
   return false;
 }  
 } else if (barcode1 != barcode || barcode2 != barcode) {
 if (PUT_LPN != "") {
   barcodeF.focus();
      return false;
    }   
} else if (barcode1 == barcode || barcode2 == barcode) {
 if (PUT_LPN == "") {
  PUT_LPN.focus();
  return false;
 }  
}else {
 if (barcode1 == barcode || barcode2 == barcode) {
  if (PUT_LPN != "") {
   return true;
  }  
 }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to me is `PUT_LPN.focus()` and `PUT_LPN == ""`. I assume its and input field and in order to compare value of it you need to use `PUT_LPN.value`. Again the syntax of `if...else` is also not valid.

```
if(condition) {
  //
} else if(condition) {
  //
} else {
  //
}
```

Also there are lot many repetitive conditions which you need to take care of.

```
function barcodeSubmit() {
  if (barcode1 === barcode || barcode2 === barcode) {
    var flag = ('' === PUT_LPN.value);
    if (flag)
      PUT_LPN.focus();
    return !flag;
  }
  barcodeF.focus();
  return false;
}
```